# Use RX on Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient (Reactive Extensions)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, azure, system.reactive, message-bus

I have a pricing application. It sends pricing requests to an Azure Service Bus Queue (could be any queue) "PricingRequestQueue". There are a number of workers that pick these up, process them and return the results to a PricingResponse Queue.

I would like to create an Observable over the PricingResponse queue. I do not require any filtering, but would like to read the messages off using the batch interface (QueueClient.BeginReceiveBatch). The queue has the number of messages expected, and has a session to read from (QueueClient.AcceptMessageSession(correlationIdentifier).

I'm still trying to get my head around RX, and this would really clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

There is the CloudFx library that adds Rx extensions to Azure.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experience.CloudFx/ (Updated link)

However I must warn you that we have found some thread leaks in the current CloudFx libraries (in particular with the table storage one - however you have not needed the Rx extensions since table storage 2.0).